# How to make from two services one service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rest, rxjs-observables

I have a angular 8 application and a service, like this:

```
export class ProfileUserService {
  user$ = this.authService.loginStatus().pipe(take(1));

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService, private authService: AuthService) {}

  getProfile(): Observable<ProfileApi> {
    return this.user$.pipe(mergeMap(({ profile }) => this.profileService.get(profile.participant)));
  }
}
```

And I have a component where I use the service where I call the method, like this:

```
export class SettingsAccountComponent extends FormCanDeactivate implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 constructor(
    private profileUserService: ProfileUserService){}

 ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.profileSubscription = this.profileUserService.getProfile().subscribe((profile: ProfileApi) => {
      this.profile = profile;
      this.deletePicture = false;
      this.buildForm();
    });
  }




}
```

But I want to call directly in the component SettingsAccountComponent : this service:

```
private profileService: ProfileService
```

But the problem is this:

```
 user$ = this.authService.loginStatus().pipe(take(1));
```

Because I need that for getting the participantId. But so my question is, how to combine  the ProfileService, like this

```
 this.profileSubscription = this.profileService.get().subscribe((profile: ProfileApi) => {
      this.profile = profile;
      this.deletePicture = false;
      this.buildForm();
    });
```

witht the:

```
 user$ = this.authService.loginStatus().pipe(take(1));
```

because now in the get() method it expecs a ParticipantId

So what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a `switchMap` can help you.

Try:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
this.profileSubscription = this.profileService.user$.pipe(
  switchMap(({ profile }) => this.profileService.get(profile.participant))
).subscribe((profile: profileAPI) => {
  this.profile = profile;
  this.deletePicture = false;
  this.buildForm();
});
```

I see you've already done `mergeMap` in your service, `switchMap` is very similar.

Comment: @can we go to chat? I think I can better explain.

Comment: The between service: ProfileUserService has to be gone. I want to use the service: ProfileService directly in the component. But I need a ParticipantId from this: user$ = this.authService.loginStatus().pipe(take(1));

Comment: I voted because I am glad it worked. Oh, the `-1` was not me.

Comment: Of course not you. But do you understand why people did not positive vote on this?? Don't understand

Comment: It happens to me too, don't let it get to you. There will always be haters :).